# Get stack trace from razor macro within umbraco

Tags: razor, umbraco

I've inherited a code base that is built on umbraco. It is using razor scripts to render the views.

Whenever there is an error I get something like this in the output:

```
Error loading Razor Script Product.cshtml
String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s
```

As you can see that is pretty useless in helping identify the error.

I've no idea if this is an umbraco or razor issue (first time I've used either)
Is there a way that you can turn on proper stack traces?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Put `umbDebugShowTrace=true` in your querystring to see the full stack trace. Make sure `umbracoDebugMode` is set to `true` in your appSettings and trace is enabled.

Comment: That does the trick! I don't suppose there is a way to always show the stack trace with the error though?

Comment: No there is not, a stack trace contains sensitive information that should not be displayed when you're not asking for it (a hacker could grab the juicy bits).

Comment: Sure, but if umbracoDebugMode is already set to true it does imply you want that info :-) anyway you've solved my problem so thanks!

Comment: For live environments you absolutely want to make sure umbracoDebugMode is set to false so your sensitive info will not be exposed. That said, we've had a few discussions as to how we can show more useful info on razor errors, food for thought. This Chrome extension can help you easily switch to debug mode by the way: http://bit.ly/fXzlk8

Comment: Ahh the extension is cool as I will surely forget what the params are :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's a very good idea to [create a website project in Visual Studio](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/getting-started-with-umbraco-what-is-next-after-you-install/setting-up-your-project-in-visual-studio) and work with your Razor scripts in there. You can `Debug > Attach to Process` and then set breakpoints, watches, step through your code etc, just like any other program.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Sebastiaan's post, you set `umbracoDebug` and `trace` to `true` in the main web.config for the Umbraco installation.  This gives fuller info on the error.